# eCatcher login error (peer not authenticated)

Tags: vpn, login, remote-access, authentication

I can no longer login in Talk2M using my good old eCatcher 3.x or 4.x.
I receive one of these error messages:

[image: Additional info I/O error while communicating with HTTP server: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException PKIX path building failed unable to find certification path]

Written out:

```
Additional info I/O error while communicating with HTTP server:
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException PKIX path building failed:
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find certification path
to requested target
```

or

[image: Server communication error : peer not authenticated]

What can I do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Some SSL certificates have expired in your [eCatcher](http://ewon.biz/ecatcher). You should either download new certificates from the eWON web site (eCatcher 4.x only). Or better still, you should upgrade to the latest version.

[This page](http://campaigns.ewon.biz/ecatcher-important-notice/) on the eWON web site contains the links to address your problem.

(*[Disclaimer](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/11252/using-superuser-com-to-warn-my-own-users): I am a member of the eWON R&D team.*)